# Understanding Multiple variables within Summations.

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, summation

I'm having trouble understanding this problem.

[image: Summation]

I thought the way of solving this problem would be to subtract the initial term(i+1) from the number of terms(n-1) and then add n-i+1. This would yield (n-1)-(i+1)+(n-i+1). However, it turns out the answer is (n-i+1)(n-i-1). If someone could explain this solution, or the summation rules behind it, that would be great, thanks!

Comment: Note that the terms $(n-i+1)$ in your sum are independent of the index $j$, so you're just adding the same term over and over. The number of terms in your sum is $(n-1)-(i+1)+1 = n-i-1$.

Comment: @A.J. So where does the multiplication come from in the final answer?

Comment: You're adding the **same** term, $(n-i+1)$, repeatedly, and there are $n-i-1$ of those terms.

Comment: Oh, I understand, now you can use the standard formula to compute this. Thanks!

Comment: It's the same idea as saying when adding $x+x+x+\ldots+x$, and there are $k$ of those $x$'s, the sum is $kx$; surely that doesn't require a formula?